# stream music with java

Tags: java, networking, tcp, stream

I am currently coding some chat program and now want to play music via a client command like:

```
/music http://somewebsite.com/somesong.mp3
```

So the link would be sent from the client that sent the song, to the server. The server should then **without** downloading the song, stream it to every client (they shouldn't download it as well). Problem is, I don't know how to stream mp3's over a TCP based connection.

My question is, if someone could provide me with libraries/tutorials/ideas/code examples of what I need.

As an alternative directly streaming music from one client's computer would be okay as well. If I (as a client) play a song on my machine (using some music player like VLC or similar) and then type a certain command (maybe **/stream**), the sounds from my soundcard would be streamed to the server and then to every client logged in.

It would be awesome if you could provide me with some advice for both, Google didn't really help so far, mainly because I don't quite understand what I should search for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The difference between "streaming" and "downloading" is a client side consideration.  The server is just sending bytes either way.

Comment: true. I just wanted to emphasize that I don't want a copy of the file somehow streamed/downloaded. that would make everything really slow (the file would need to be downloaded completely before playing). the song should start immediately after entering the command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a library that does exactly what I want to do: 
http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html

```
public void play() {
        String song = "http://www.ntonyx.com/mp3files/Morning_Flower.mp3";
        Player mp3player = null;
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        try {
          in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(song).openStream());
          mp3player = new Player(in);
          mp3player.play();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        }

}
```

Hope that helps everyone with a similar question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way could be using a Servlet. Set the content type as "audio/mpeg3". The servlet will stream the bytes and user will be able to play music in his browser.