# How to read and play realtime sound stream in java?

Tags: java, audio, real-time

I'm using Java to read and play some real time audio streams such as the voice from radio station.

I have the real time web address like [this one](http://my.radiostation.com/program1/audio) and it can be played in a web browser.

How can I play it using Java language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MP3SPI is a Java Service Provider Interface that adds MP3 (MPEG 1/2/2.5 Layer 1/2/3) audio format support for Java Platform. It supports streaming, ID3v2 frames, Equalizer etc. It is based on JLayer and Tritonus Java libraries.

You can use this library [MP3 SPI for Java Sound](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html) , and its documentation [here](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/documents.html).

[Library reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818155/stream-music-with-java)